# scale group of objects

Tags: linear-algebra

I've 2 objects,

```
{
    x: 100,
    y: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
},
{
    x: 220,
    y: 50,
    width: 50,
    height: 50
}
```

these objects grouped together, when they are scaled they scaled from the center of group, can you help me to know how to scale the objects  from group center and get x,y for each object?

i'm not the best in math and this maybe easy for you, but not me :(

demo: https://codepen.io/solaimankmail/pen/QgQVvv?editors=0010

Comment: What do you mean by scaling the objects from the group centre?

Comment: on my demo, each object is scaled by it's own center(origin), otherwise, when scale group of objects, they must scale by one center.

Comment: What do you mean by scale?

Comment: resize ... have you checked the demo?

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/transformationsrev7.shtml This page talks about the enlargement and the centre of enlargement. You want the centre of enlargement to be the centre of your object group.

Comment: @SolaimanKmail If the context is HTML, I think you'd probably be better off putting all the objects inside a container `div` and scaling that container `div`.

Comment: Yes it make sense to do that in some cases, my case different a bit, and i can't just put them  in a div and scale, i need the calculated values to be stored in DB, and i don't wan't to use getRectBounding nor offset to get the bounds